# how to write a function to get monthly, weekly data from daily in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as below and I need to write a function to convert this data to weekly(sunday as week end date) or monthly depending on the input parameter:-

sample daily price df data:

```
date             price_chair     vol_glass
02-09-2018         2              6
03-09-2018         1              5
04-09-2018         3              6
05-09-2018         4              8
10-09-2018         5              10
15-09-2018         2              10
18-09-2018         2              10
01-10-2018         3              20
```

if option is monthly, then take average of price chair and sum of glass vol for a month, these columns can vary:

```
year_month        price_chair_avg_monthly     vol_glass_sum_monthly
2018-09            2.71                    55
2018-10            3                       20
```

if option is weekly, then take average of price chair and sum of glass vol for a week, these columns can vary:

```
date    price_chair_avg_weekly  vol_glass_sum_weekly
02/09/18    2                    6
09/09/18    2.67                 19
16/09/18    3.5                  20
23/09/18    2                    10
30/09/18        
07/10/18    3                    20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) with dictionary for specify columns and resample functions:

```
#if first column is not index
#df = df.set_index('date')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)

df1 = df.resample('MS').agg({'price_chair':'mean','vol_glass':'sum'})
print (df1)
            price_chair  vol_glass
date                              
2018-09-01     2.714286         55
2018-10-01     3.000000         20

df2 = df.resample('W').agg({'price_chair':'mean','vol_glass':'sum'})
print (df2)
            price_chair  vol_glass
date                              
2018-09-02     2.000000          6
2018-09-09     2.666667         19
2018-09-16     3.500000         20
2018-09-23     2.000000         10
2018-09-30          NaN          0
2018-10-07     3.000000         20
```

Comment: hi jezrael, thankss again for this! do you know what to select for biweekly in case

Comment: @user3222101 - Then change `W` to `2W`

Comment: @user3222101 - I see your new question - can you add this code from my answer and also expected output? Then no reason for downvoting.

Comment: Thank you jezrael, have added there plus I am trying to solve as well.
thanks again